# How does the velocity vector have this form?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds, tangent-spaces

This is Example 9.1b in Lee's *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds* which is about integral curves. He says

> Let $W = x\partial/\partial y - y \partial/\partial x$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$. If $\gamma: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ is a smooth curve, written in standard coordinates as $\gamma(t) = (x(t), y(t))$, then the condition $\gamma'(t) = W_{\gamma(t)}$ for $\gamma$ to be an integral curve translates to $$x'(t)\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\Big|_{\gamma(t)}  + y'(t)\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\Big|_{\gamma(t)} = x(t)\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\Big|_{\gamma(t)} - y(t)\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\Big|_{\gamma(t)}.$$

How does how obtain the left hand side above for $\gamma'(t)$?

Comment: the definition of the derivative of $\gamma(t)$ is the left side hand of the equation

Comment: @monotoneoperator Lee defines $\gamma'(t_0) = d\gamma(d/dt|_{t_0})$, how does this imply the left hand side above?

Comment: the follow is the answer

Comment: This is just a special case of the general formula for the velocity in coordinates, which appears near the bottom of page 69.

Comment: @JackLee Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know from basic geometry of curves that the tangent vector of a curve $\gamma(t)=(x(t),y(t))$ is defined at any point by $\gamma'(t)=(x'(t),y'(t))$. The LHS is just another way of writing this, calling the standar basis vectors of $\mathbb{R}^2$ $\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\right)_{\gamma(t)}$ and $\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right)_{\gamma(t)}$, respectively (remember that the tangent space changes with the point; in the trivial case of $\mathbb{R}^2$ we usually forget about this, but the author is stressing this point-dependence with the suscript $\gamma(t)$ below the partial derivatives).

Comment: Is there a way to reach that expression for $\gamma'(t)$ using the more general definition $\gamma'(t_0) = d\gamma(d/dt|_{t_0})$?

Comment: @CBBAM For a differentiable map between open sets of affine spaces, the associated map between tangent spaces is $\textbf{defined}$ as the linear map whose expression with respect to the canonical basis is given by the matrix equal to the usual Jacobian matrix . The Jacobian of $\gamma$ at a point $t_0$ is $d\gamma_{t_0}=(x'(t_0), y'(t_0))$, which is the same as saying that $d\gamma_{t_0}(d/dt_{t_0})=(x'(t_0), y'(t_0))$.

Comment: @CBBAM I know that, when treating with functions between affine spaces, this notation seems rather redundant, as we are just renaming things we know very well, namely, derivatives and Jacobian matrices. The necessity of changing to this new notation, stressing always the point-dependence, becomes clear when we treat with differentiable manifolds that are not open sets of affine space.